# Can a Chrome extension act as a web app in place of a website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Chrome extension that is supposed to completely replace a specific website's pages with a new UI. In other words, when the user visits said website, the extension should "intercept" it seamlessly and display the new "app" (preserving the URL and without opening a new tab or window). I currently use a content script to manipulate the DOM, but it's too messy.

Chrome apps such as [Google Docs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs/aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake/) achieve the same goal through [URL handlers](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/url_handlers), but they're not an option since they're now deprecated.

Currently, I'm aware of two options:

- Intercept the URL and redirect it to an extension URL. *I want the URL to be preserved.*
- Use a content script to stop the page from loading at `document_start` (using `window.stop()`) and then "inject" the new app. Apparently, that works, but it sounds quite hacky and prone to unexpected glitches.

What I'd like to know:

- Is the second approach good enough? What limitations and other issues will I face if I use it?
- Is there any other approach that is at least as good (and preferably designed for this purpose)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a chrome *app* in a tab, only in a window. I don't think they have content scripts either.

**Also, chrome apps are now only available on chrome os when you publish it for the first time (existing chrome apps work for any os).**

---

To solve your question, you could use an extension with content scripts and just open up an `iframe` fullscreen so the url is preserved in the omnibox and it could have the page you want in the iframe as the page that would be in the app.

Content handlers are meant for opening a special protocol url to do something like send an email, etc. Examples would be like tel://, sms://, mailto:, etc.
So you would not want this. Also they aren't that noticable when approving to handle the protocol.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the issue with apps and wasn't planning to develop one, and I said so in the question. (I may have misunderstood the inner workings of the Docs app, but that was not the point.) What I really want to know at first is whether using the `window.stop()` method is "safe" enough (in terms of predictability of behavior). Thanks for the `iframe` suggestion, I'll look into that. Would it offer any advantage over the method I just mentioned?

Comment: `window.stop()` works perfect for Chrome. The only browser it doesn't work for is IE. S you should be fine.